# TSQL Incrementing Count of Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a UI that allows a user to select one or more fields they want to add to a table. This data also has an `orderID` associated with it that determines the field order.

When the user adds new fields, I need to find the last `orderID` this user used and increment it by 1, submitting all of the new fields.

For example, if there is a single record that already exists in the database, it would have an `orderID` of 1. When I choose to add three more fields, it would check to see the last `orderID` I used (1) and then increment it for each of the new records it adds, 1-4.

```
-- Get the last ID orderID for this user and increment it by 1 as our starting point
DECLARE @lastID INT = (SELECT TOP 1 orderID FROM dbo.BS_ContentRequests_Tasks_User_Fields WHERE QID = @QID ORDER BY orderID DESC)
SET @lastID = @lastID+1;

-- Create a temp table to hold our fields that we are adding
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (fieldID int, orderID int)

-- Insert our fields and incremented numbers
INSERT INTO @temp( fieldID, orderID )
SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('selected[1]', 'int'),
       @lastID++
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/data/fields/field') AS ParamValues(x1);
```

Obviously the `@lastID++` part is where my issue is but hopefully it helps to understand what I am trying to do.

What other method could be used to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER() ought to do it.

```
select  x.Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.Value) + @lastID
    from (
        select 10 ParamValues.x1.value('selected[1]', 'int') Value
            from @xml.nodes('/root/data/fields/field') AS ParamValues(x1)
        ) x
```

Comment: I got this error - `Msg 5308, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BS_Update_ContentRequests_AvailableFields, Line 43
Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.`

Comment: Hmm.  I updated it to use the value itself in the order by clause... didn't think it was necessary, but I guess it was.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a column with IDENTITY(1,1)

Answer (score 0):

**If you want OrderID to be unique across the entire table then see below:**

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37825036/6448783) to take a look at another post that addresses this issue.

There are multiple ways to approach this issue, but in this case, the easiest, while reasonable, means may be to use an identity column. However, that is not as extensible as using a sequence. If you feel that you may need more flexibility in the future, then use a sequence.

**If you want OrderID to be unique across the fields inserted in one batch then see below:**

You should take a closer look at Chris Steele's answer.